# How does lparam and wparam work in this specific code example?

Tags: windows, event-handling, controls

I'm reading at some coding examples from Microsoft. And get confused by this combined key part.

```cs
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        if (wParam == VK_RETURN && (lParam & 0x60000000) == 0x20000000)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I don't understand, this code is about switching the application between fullscreen and windowed when pressing Alt+Enter. I get that WM_SYSKEYDOWN is holding Alt, and VK_RETURN is pressing Enter. So when they put together it means pressing Enter while holding Alt, but how do these two parameters work? Why Enter is in wParam and what does the lParam part on the right mean? What does the value of lParam represents? Please help.

I have another thing I'd like to ask.

Why it uses 0x60000000? It is a 31 bit start with 2 "1"s followed by 29 "0"s. From the document provided by tkausl, the 31th bit of WM_SYSKEYDOWN is always 0, so with a "&" operator, there should be no way the output will have a "1" at that bit, so why not just use 0x20000000 which should give the exactly same result?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-syskeydown

Comment: Thank you tkausl. I was searching about wParam and WndProc, so I just didn't find this topic. Thank you very much!